# access out side of website folder

Tags: php, web, root, directory-structure

I want to know whether it is possible or not, otherwise better solution
Here is my directory structure

```
/home/lankaven/public_html/smartysys/websites
/home/lankaven/public_html/smartysys/resources
/home/lankaven/public_html/smartysys/websites/Abc
/home/lankaven/public_html/smartysys/websites/Xyz
```

Abc directory is website abc.com
xyz directory is website xyz.com

so is that possible to access both websites to the resources directory to use images and php files?

how to insert image to the index.php file in abc folder form resources folder image.jpg?

Comment: It depends entirely on how your server is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images and other content are requested by the browser. So they can get the content from the other website trough the URL of the other website. For example:

```
http://example.com/img/image.png
```

If you have the permissions to reach the other directory with PHP it is possible to use the other PHP files. If you want to go a level down in the directory structure you can use "../". For example:

You want to read a PHP file named file.php in the directory Abc from the Xyz directory. Than you can use the following path:

```
../Abc/file.php
```